# WPF MVVM ICommand not executing on first click

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, xaml, mvvm

We are creating a WPF application with MVVM architecture that uses WCF service to validate users.
We have designed a login screen and using ICommand property for login button.

The problem is the login is happening after 3 clicks  and I cant figure out why. All the other buttons in application are working fine on first click. And the other thing is if user name or password is entered wrong it is throwing a login failed method after two clicks

Here is the Xaml

```
< Button x:Name="btnLogin"
                        Width="120"
                        Height="25"
                        Margin="0,0,0,0"
                        Command="{Binding Validate}"
                        Content="Login"
                        FontSize="14"                           
                        ToolTipService.ToolTip="Login" />
```

This is the property we are binding to the command

```
public ICommand Validate
    {
        get { return new LoginCommands(ValidateUser); }
    }
```

This is the class that implemnts ICommand Interface

```
class LoginCommands:ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;


    public LoginCommands(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }


    public LoginCommands(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

This is the ValidateUser Method

```
     private void ServiceValidUser()
    {
        if (SelectedLoginType.LoginTypeValue == 1)
        {
            LoginDetails.EncryptPW = LoginDetails.EncryptWindow(Password);
            _model.ValidateUser(LoginName, LoginDetails.EncryptWindow(Password),
               byte.Parse(SelectedUserType.EmpTypeValue.ToString()),
               byte.Parse(SelectedLoginType.LoginTypeValue.ToString()),
               (s, e) => ValidUser = e.Result.ValidateUserResult.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            LoginDetails.EncryptPW = LoginDetails.Encrypt(Password);
            _model.ValidateUser(LoginName, LoginDetails.Encrypt(Password),
              byte.Parse(SelectedUserType.EmpTypeValue.ToString()),
              byte.Parse(SelectedLoginType.LoginTypeValue.ToString()),
              (s, e) => ValidUser = e.Result.ValidateUserResult.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void CheckUser()
    {
        if (ValidUser == "0" || ValidUser == "2")
        {
            _model.GetLoginDetails(LoginName, LoginDetails.EncryptPW,
                byte.Parse(SelectedUserType.EmpTypeValue.ToString()),
                byte.Parse(SelectedLoginType.LoginTypeValue.ToString()),
                (s, e) => LoginResult = e.Result.GetLoginInfoResult);
               ErrorMessage = "";
        }
        else if (ValidUser == "1")
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Opps.! Invalid Password..!";
        }
        else if(ValidUser!="3")
        {
            ErrorMessage = "User Not Found..!";

        }

        if(LoginResult!=null && ValidUser=="0")
        {
            LoginDetails.LoginInfo = LoginResult.FirstOrDefault();
            LoginDetails.UserName = LoginName;
            LoginDetails.UserType = byte.Parse(SelectedUserType.EmpTypeValue.ToString());
            LoginDetails.LoginType= byte.Parse(SelectedLoginType.LoginTypeValue.ToString());
            var window = Utilities.GetWindowRef("LoginScreen");
            window.Close();
        }
    }
```

Please ask if you need anymore information.

Comment: When you say the login isn't happening, where is the error?  Is the command being fired?  As a matter of practice, I also probably wouldn't re-create the `Validate` object every time it's requested either.

Comment: Where's the code for `LoginCommands`?

Comment: Thanks for reply @tencntraze all the 3 times command is being fired and it is not throwing any error.

Comment: @DanielMann sorry for that I have edit my question now.

Comment: Did you try to add a breakpoint in the ValidateUser method to see what was happening?

Comment: Since the command is actually firing and your code is being hit, I think that we'll have trouble debugging this since we don't know what your WCF service is doing.  Is `LoginResult` null or is `ValidUser != 0`?  You should set breakpoints/logging for those cases so you can see what your service is doing.

Comment: In the getter for your `Validate` property, you're always returning a new instance of your command. You might not want to be doing this... Instead, give it a backing field with an initializer - this way you'll always return the same instance. Not sure if this has anything to do with your problem, but I think this is a problem nonetheless.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for suggestion I will do that on my code. I thought that since the value is returned only once that would not be a problem.

Comment: By placing break points what I have observed is this. On first click everything is getting intialized but the service results are null. On second click ValidateUser service is returning the result but GetLoginDetails result is null.On third click GetLoginDetails service is returning results so the login is happening on third click.

Comment: Also CanExecute method keeps on executing several times. Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: Re: CanExecute executing multiple times: Yes, CanExecute runs when the UI is updated/gains input in an attempt to determine if anything would fail, thus disabling the control for you.

Comment: @bland thanks for the explanation. This is my first MVVM project so I asked.

Comment: Also all the service requests are async. can that be a causing this  problem?

Comment: Ahh finally making sync requests to service instead of async worked. But still confusing why it is not working for async calls